# How do input elements check if strings match the regular expression specified in the pattern attribute?

Tags: javascript, regex, html, validation, input

I am creating an npm module which will be a collection of regular expression validation patterns from http://html5pattern.com/ and other sources.

My question came about when I tried testing some of the expressions. I am using [Ava.js](https://github.com/avajs) to do simple assertions.

Internally, when testing regular expressions, Ava uses the RegEx `test()` method. So, for example, `/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/.test("Us3rN@m3")` would return `true`.

However, when you actually use `/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/` as the regular expression for an input element's pattern attribute, `"Us3rN@m3"` returns `false`.

So I am guessing that internally, the input element is doing a different test?

The HTML [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-input-pattern) states that the given regular expression is *compiled as a JavaScript regular expression with only the "u" flag specified*, which does not tell me much.

If I write the regular expression like this `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test("Us3rNm3")`, it returns `true` just like the input element, but I am not sure if this is how it works internally?

Comment: `/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/.test("Us3rN@m3")` should never return true in any typical programming language AFAIK.  Are you sure you are showing us the correct code?

Comment: According to [`pattern` attribute documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-pattern-attribute): *This regular expression language used for this attribute is the same as that used in JavaScript, except that the pattern attribute is **matched against the entire value**, not just any subset (**somewhat as if it implied a `^(?:` at the start of the pattern and a `)$` at the end**)*.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - it does in JavaScript. "Us3rN" is what causes it to return true.

Comment: Read Wiktor's comment above, which seems to explain what is happening here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Ah! I read that page so many times I must have glossed over that. Makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correctly test HTML5 patterns, make sure you wrap the whole string pattern with `^(?:` and `)$` to ensure entire string matching.

According to [`pattern` attribute documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-pattern-attribute):

> This regular expression language used for this attribute is the same as that used in JavaScript, except that the pattern attribute is matched against the entire value, not just any subset (somewhat as if it implied a `^(?:` at the start of the pattern and a `)$` at the end).